# Cannot add two columns in bootstrap card

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to add two columns inside a card:

```
<div class="card bg-white black-content">
  <div class="card-body">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
      <label>test</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
       <label>test2</label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The problem is that `test2` doesn't appear on the right side of `test` but at the bottom (they stack on top of each other), seems that `Bootstrap` create two `rows`. What I'm doing wrong?

Notice that `label` is just an example, I have other content inside it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why are you closing the `label` tag with `</test>`? Also, you need a `row` to put columns inside of it

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="card bg-white black-content">
  <div class="card-body">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12 col-sm-6">
        <label>test</label>
      </div>
      <div class="col-12 col-sm-6">
        <label>test2</label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @teres no need to apologize lol, just a heads up :) also notice the `.row` that acts as a container for the columns

Comment: @IvanS95 just a heads up: in BS4 there are no `col-xs-*` classes anymore. I edited your answer with the proper `col-*` classes.

Answer (score 3):

Like others have said, all columns needs to be wrapped by a `<div class="row"></div>` element. Also, note that `col-xs-*` is not more available on `Bootstrap 4`, instead you have to use `col-*`. Anyway, in your example, that was redundant... because columns will take all the `12` available columns for breakpoints lowers than the `lowest-specified` one (in your case this was `SM`).

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-wHAiFfRlMFy6i5SRaxvfOCifBUQy1xHdJ/yoi7FRNXMRBu5WHdZYu1hA6ZOblgut" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B0UglyR+jN6CkvvICOB2joaf5I4l3gm9GU6Hc1og6Ls7i6U/mkkaduKaBhlAXv9k" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="card bg-white black-content">
  <div class="card-header text-center">
    CARD
  </div>
  <div class="card-body">
  <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-6 bg-info text-center">
         <label>test</label>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6 bg-warning text-center">
        <label>test2</label>
      </div>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to add `<div class="row">` to wrap your columns:

```
<div class="card bg-white black-content">
    <div class="card-body">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
           <label>test</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
           <label>test2</label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```